# Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

So i am trying to read lines and then split them in two with strtok . So if i would read "nice dog" it will first print what i read and then will print using the strtok commands  "nice" and "dog" on the next line . But after second input i got Segmentation fault .Also , what does free(buf) do ? I've seen that the error is at this line : "strcpy(name, strtok(NULL, " "));" This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf;
    char command[32];
    char name[32];

    while((buf = readline("\n"))!=NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(buf,"exit")==0)
            break;

        printf("%s\n",buf);

        strcpy(command, strtok(buf, " "));
        printf("%s\n", command);
        strcpy(name, strtok(NULL, " "));
        printf("%s\n", name);
        if(buf[0]!=NULL)
        add_history(buf);
    }
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `readline` do?

Comment: Check your `strtok` output before using it.

Comment: reads your line input

Comment: Free deallocates the memory that you get from the heap, so using malloc or one of the relating functions. Whenever you malloc something you have to free it otherwise you will have memory leaks

Comment: `readline` may be buggy. it's clearer if you show us the code of `readline`.

Comment: The terminal I/O handler does everything needed, so much better to use fgets() rather than readline().  and readline requires the I/O to be in raw mode, which has not been done here.  readline does not append a nul byte to the input, so strtok will fail.

Comment: This line: if(buf[0]!=NULL) should never work, as a single character will never be equal to NULL (which is a void pointer to 0)  Perhaps what you meant was if( '\0' != buf[0] )

Comment: readline is a line editor, confined to a single line input from a terminal that is in 'raw' mode, used for handling all the edit keystrokes the user may enter.  It is a slow, huge function that (probably) should never be used as a 'cooked' mode (the normal condition) terminal I/O handles all the keystrokes (and mouse clicks) a user should ever need,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the result of `strtok` if it's `NULL` meaning that no tokens where found you will get `segmentation fault`

```
char *pointer;
pointer = strtok(buf, " ");
if (pointer != NULL)
    strcpy(command, pointer);
```

also, `readline` allocates new memory on every call so you should `free` inside the `while` loop.

Fix it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf;
    char command[32];
    char name[32];

    while((buf = readline("\n"))!=NULL)
    {
        char *pointer;
        if (strcmp(buf,"exit")==0)
            break;

        printf("%s\n",buf);

        pointer = strtok(buf, " ");
        if (pointer != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(command, pointer);
            /* Don't print poitner otherwise since it is unintialized */
            printf("%s\n", pointer);
        }

        /* subsequent calls to strtok must have first argument NULL */
        pointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (pointer != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(name, pointer);
            printf("%s\n", pointer);
        }

        if (buf != NULL) // this is never FALSE because of the while condition
            add_history(buf);
        free(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you also have to make sure that `command` and `name` will be big enough to fit the resulting stirng.

Comment: Still got segmentation fault .

Comment: I am trying to read this exact text : " hi mate.txt" . It works great but then, on the second input it give me segmentation fault .

Comment: @aNNgeL0 The text you are trying to read is irrelevant, one thing to notice is that your program will run forever, you must add a condition to the while loop to stop whenever the user enters a given string like `quit` or something.

Comment: Worked as a charm . Thanks iharob . I have a stop coindtion but didn't showed it here . Why didnt it worked with that pointer ? I was reading "hi mate.txt" and then "hi" and then it give me segmentation fault .

Comment: @aNNgeL0 The problem is that `strcpy` does not handle `NULL` arguments you must pass non-`NULL` arguments. An for the `free` inside the `while` part, just type `man readline` in your terminal and read the manual.